# Xamarin.UWP Release build failed for error RHB0002 and error ILT0005

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp

I have a code auto-generating framework to build Xamarin cross platform APP. When the size of APP is not very large, Xamarin.UWP built success for Windows and Android platform. Until I generated a new larger APP, release build failed, with NO more NuGet package or DLL import added. The new APP can be debug successfully in Windows, and be deployed to Android successful. It’s very confusing.
I have taken several days to solve this problem , but I can’t.
I have tried many combination of configurations:

In Default.rd.xml， I changed

```
<Assembly Name="*Application*" Dynamic="Required All" />
```

to :

```
<Namespace Name=" AppName" Dynamic="Excluded" Serialize="Excluded" />
```

In csproj file, I have add some trick setting from web:

```
<Optimize>false</Optimize>
<UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
<Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
<UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
<Use64BitCompiler>true</Use64BitCompiler>
<SingleThreadNUTC>true</SingleThreadNUTC>
<ShortcutGenericAnalysis>true</ShortcutGenericAnalysis>
<UseDotNetNativeSharedAssemblyFrameworkPackage>false</UseDotNetNativeSharedAssemblyFrameworkPackage>
<AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
```

This is the end part of build log which contain the error message (ps: "Failed to locate method" is also existed in smaller APP release build but not lead to fail):

```
83>  Done building target "MDILBindPrepare" in file "Binder".
83>  
83>  Generating fixups for native code
83>  Task "MDILBind"
83>  Launching 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\runtime.win10-x86.microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.10-rel-29722-00\tools\x86\ilc\Tools\rhbind.exe @"D:\AppName.UWP\obj\x86\Release\ilc\intermediate\rhbindargs.AppName.UWP.rsp"'
83>  OS VERSION: major: 6  minor: 2
83>  MDIL: D:\AppName.UWP\obj\x86\Release\ilc\intermediate\MDIL\AppName.UWP.mdilexe
83>  MDILPDB: D:\AppName.UWP\obj\x86\Release\ilc\intermediate\MDIL\AppName.UWP.mdilpdb
83>  IL: D:\AppName.UWP\obj\x86\Release\ilc\intermediate\MDIL\AppName.UWP.ilexe
83>  NI: D:\AppName.UWP\obj\x86\Release\ilc\intermediate\Native\AppName.UWP.dll
83>  SHIM: D:\AppName.UWP\obj\x86\Release\ilc\intermediate\Native\AppName.UWP.exe
83>  REDHAWK_RUNTIME_DLL_NAME_A=mrt100_app.dll
83>  pdb: D:\AppName.UWP\obj\x86\Release\ilc\intermediate\Native\AppName.UWP.pdb
83>  RHBIND : warning RHB0003: Failed to locate method 0A0218F7 in MDIL debug output
83>  RHBIND : warning RHB0003: Failed to locate method 0A0218F8 in MDIL debug output
...
83>  RHBIND : warning RHB0003: Failed to locate method 0A0E0680 in MDIL debug output
83>  RHBIND : warning RHB0003: Failed to locate method 0A0E6501 in MDIL debug output
83>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.10-rel-29722-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(805,5): error : RHBIND : error RHB0002: Failed to write PDB.
83>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.10-rel-29722-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(805,5): error : ILT0005: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\runtime.win10-x86.microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.10-rel-29722-00\tools\x86\ilc\Tools\rhbind.exe @"D:\AppName.UWP\obj\x86\Release\ilc\intermediate\rhbindargs.AppName.UWP.rsp"' returned exit code 2
83>  Done executing task "MDILBind" -- FAILED.
83>  Done building target "MDILBind" in file "Binder" -- FAILED.
83>  Done building project "Binder" -- FAILED.
83>  Compilation failed
83>  
…
83>
83>"D:\AppName.UWP\AppName.UWP.csproj" (_GenerateAppxPackage target) (1) ->
83>(BuildNativePackage target) -> 
83>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.10-rel-29722-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(805,5): warning :       MCG : warning MCG0007: Unresolved P/Invoke method 'api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-0.dll!CreateBindCtx' for method 'System.Void System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalInterop.CreateBindCtx(System.UInt32, System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IBindCtx)'. Calling this method would throw exception at runtime. Please make sure the P/Invoke either points to a Windows API allowed in UWP applications, or a native DLL that is part of the package. If for some reason your P/Invoke does not satisfy those requirements, please use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP APIs.
83>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.10-rel-29722-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(805,5): warning :       MCG : warning MCG0007: Unresolved P/Invoke method 'api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-0.dll!MkParseDisplayName' for method 'System.Void System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalInterop.MkParseDisplayName(System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IBindCtx, System.String, System.UInt32, System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IMoniker)'. Calling this method would throw exception at runtime. Please make sure the P/Invoke either points to a Windows API allowed in UWP applications, or a native DLL that is part of the package. If for some reason your P/Invoke does not satisfy those requirements, please use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP APIs.
83>
83>
83>"D:\AppName.UWP\AppName.UWP.csproj" (_GenerateAppxPackage target) (1) ->
83>(BuildNativePackage target) -> 
83>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.10-rel-29722-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(805,5): error : RHBIND : error RHB0002: Failed to write PDB.
83>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.10-rel-29722-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(805,5): error : ILT0005: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\runtime.win10-x86.microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.10-rel-29722-00\tools\x86\ilc\Tools\rhbind.exe @"D:\AppName.UWP\obj\x86\Release\ilc\intermediate\rhbindargs.AppName.UWP.rsp"' returned exit code 2
83>
83>    2 Warning(s)
83>    2 Error(s)
83>
83>Time Elapsed 00:20:36.49
========== Build: 82 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Package: 0 succeeded, 3 failed ===========
```

This log indicate method 'api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-0.dll!CreateBindCtx' and method 'api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-0.dll!MkParseDisplayName' is the reason. The hole solution to build has **NOT** any local reference or DllImport, but NuGet packages as follow:

```
<PackageReference Include="SixLabors.ImageSharp" Version="1.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="ZXing.Net.Mobile" Version="3.1.0-beta2" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite" Version="5.0.8" />
<PackageReference Include="EPPlus" Version="5.7.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Plugin.HybridWebView" Version="1.0.0.2-alpha" />
<PackageReference Include="Plugin.NFC" Version="0.1.20" />
<PackageReference Include="SixLabors.ImageSharp" Version="1.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp" Version="2.80.3" />
<PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.Views.Forms" Version="2.80.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Controls.SignaturePad.Forms" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.7.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms" Version="2.4.11.982" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="5.0.0.2083" />
<PackageReference Include="Plugin.MediaManager.Forms" Version="1.0.9" />
<PackageReference Include="Plugin.AudioRecorder" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugin.Media" Version="5.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms" Version="3.1.0-beta2" />
```

These packages **SHOULD** be all right beacuse they have been released! **Why** some of it need add [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true)]??  I can’t find witch line of code, witch method, which class or which NuGet package cause this failure. And I don’t know where to set the indicate of [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true)].

I have searched every file in D:\AppName.UWP\obj\x86\Release\ilc. I found CreateBindCtx exited in PInvoke.g.cs, but I don‘t know how to deal with it：

```
namespace __Interop
{
    /// <summary>
    /// P/Invoke class for module 'api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-0.dll'
    /// </summary>
    public unsafe static partial class api_ms_win_core_com_l1_1_0_dll
    {
        // Signature, CreateBindCtx, [fwd] [return] [EETypeRva:0x00042030] void__int, [fwd] [in] [EETypeRva:0x000419B0] uint__unsigned int, [fwd] [out] [managedbyref] [nativebyref] [EETypeRva:0x00043660] System_Runtime_InteropServices_ComTypes_IBindCtx__System_Private_Interop__System_Runtime_InteropServices_ComTypes__IBindCtx__System_Private_Interop *, 
        [global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.McgPInvokeMarshalStub("System.Private.Interop, Version=999.999.999.999, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", "System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalInterop", "CreateBindCtx")]
        public static void CreateBindCtx(
                    uint reserved, 
                    out global::System_Runtime_InteropServices_ComTypes.IBindCtx__System_Private_Interop ppbc)
        {
            // Setup
            void* unsafe_ppbc = default(void*);
            int unsafe___hr;
            try
            {
                // Marshalling
                unsafe_ppbc = null;
                // Call to native method
                unsafe___hr = global::__Interop.api_ms_win_core_com_l1_1_0_dll_PInvokes.CreateBindCtx(
                                    reserved, 
                                    &(unsafe_ppbc)
                                );
                global::System.Diagnostics.DebugAnnotations.PreviousCallContainsDebuggerStepInCode();
                ppbc = (global::System_Runtime_InteropServices_ComTypes.IBindCtx__System_Private_Interop)global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.McgMarshal.ComInterfaceToObject(
                                    ((global::System.IntPtr)unsafe_ppbc), 
                                    global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.TypeOfHelper.RuntimeTypeHandleOf("System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IBindCtx,System.Private.Interop, Version=999.999.999.999, Culture=neutra" +
                                            "l, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")
                                );
                // Return
            }
            finally
            {
                // Cleanup
                global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.McgMarshal.ComSafeRelease(new global::System.IntPtr(((void*)unsafe_ppbc)));
            }
        }

        // Signature, MkParseDisplayName, [fwd] [return] [EETypeRva:0x00042030] void__int, [fwd] [in] [EETypeRva:0x00043660] System_Runtime_InteropServices_ComTypes_IBindCtx__System_Private_Interop__System_Runtime_InteropServices_ComTypes__IBindCtx__System_Private_Interop *, [fwd] [in] [EETypeRva:0x00041B44] string__wchar_t *, [fwd] [out] [managedbyref] [nativebyref] [EETypeRva:0x000419B0] uint__unsigned int, [fwd] [out] [managedbyref] [nativebyref] [EETypeRva:0x00043660] System_Runtime_InteropServices_ComTypes_IMoniker__System_Private_Interop__System_Runtime_InteropServices_ComTypes__IMoniker__System_Private_Interop *, 
        [global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.McgPInvokeMarshalStub("System.Private.Interop, Version=999.999.999.999, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", "System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalInterop", "MkParseDisplayName")]
        public static void MkParseDisplayName(
                    global::System_Runtime_InteropServices_ComTypes.IBindCtx__System_Private_Interop pbc, 
                    string szUserName, 
                    out uint pchEaten, 
                    out global::System_Runtime_InteropServices_ComTypes.IMoniker__System_Private_Interop ppmk)
        {
            // Setup
            void* unsafe_pbc = default(void*);
            ushort* unsafe_szUserName = default(ushort*);
            void* unsafe_ppmk = default(void*);
            int unsafe___hr;
            try
            {
                // Marshalling
                unsafe_pbc = (void*)global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.McgMarshal.ObjectToComInterface(
                                    pbc, 
                                    global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.TypeOfHelper.RuntimeTypeHandleOf("System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IBindCtx,System.Private.Interop, Version=999.999.999.999, Culture=neutra" +
                                            "l, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")
                                );
                fixed (char* pinned_szUserName = szUserName)
                {
                    unsafe_szUserName = (ushort*)pinned_szUserName;
                    fixed (uint* pinned_pchEaten = &(pchEaten))
                    {
                        unsafe_ppmk = null;
                        // Call to native method
                        unsafe___hr = global::__Interop.api_ms_win_core_com_l1_1_0_dll_PInvokes.MkParseDisplayName(
                                            unsafe_pbc, 
                                            unsafe_szUserName, 
                                            pinned_pchEaten, 
                                            &(unsafe_ppmk)
                                        );
                        global::System.Diagnostics.DebugAnnotations.PreviousCallContainsDebuggerStepInCode();
                        ppmk = (global::System_Runtime_InteropServices_ComTypes.IMoniker__System_Private_Interop)global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.McgMarshal.ComInterfaceToObject(
                                            ((global::System.IntPtr)unsafe_ppmk), 
                                            global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.TypeOfHelper.RuntimeTypeHandleOf("System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IMoniker,System.Private.Interop, Version=999.999.999.999, Culture=neutra" +
                                                    "l, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")
                                        );
                    }
                }
                // Return
            }
            finally
            {
                // Cleanup
                global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.McgMarshal.ComSafeRelease(new global::System.IntPtr(((void*)unsafe_pbc)));
                global::System.GC.KeepAlive(pbc);
                global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.McgMarshal.ComSafeRelease(new global::System.IntPtr(((void*)unsafe_ppmk)));
            }
        }

        // Signature, CoCreateInstance, [fwd] [return] [EETypeRva:0x000419B0] int__int, [fwd] [in] [EETypeRva:0x000419B0] byte___ptrunsigned char *, [fwd] [in] [EETypeRva:0x000419B0] System_IntPtr____w64 int, [fwd] [in] [EETypeRva:0x000419B0] int__int, [fwd] [in] [EETypeRva:0x000419B0] byte___ptrunsigned char *, [fwd] [out] [managedbyref] [nativebyref] [EETypeRva:0x000419B0] System_IntPtr____w64 int, 
        [global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.McgPInvokeMarshalStub("System.Private.StackTraceGenerator, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", "Internal.StackTraceGenerator.StackTraceGenerator", "CoCreateInstance")]
        public static int CoCreateInstance(
                    byte* rclsid, 
                    global::System.IntPtr pUnkOuter, 
                    int dwClsContext, 
                    byte* riid, 
                    out global::System.IntPtr ppv)
        {
            // Setup
            int unsafe___value;
            // Marshalling
            fixed (global::System.IntPtr* pinned_ppv = &(ppv))
            {
                // Call to native method
                unsafe___value = global::__Interop.api_ms_win_core_com_l1_1_0_dll_PInvokes.CoCreateInstance(
                                    ((byte*)rclsid), 
                                    pUnkOuter, 
                                    dwClsContext, 
                                    ((byte*)riid), 
                                    pinned_ppv
                                );
                global::System.Diagnostics.DebugAnnotations.PreviousCallContainsDebuggerStepInCode();
            }
            // Return
            return unsafe___value;
        }
    }

    public unsafe static partial class api_ms_win_core_debug_l1_1_0_dll_PInvokes
    {
        [global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("api-ms-win-core-debug-l1-1-0.dll", CallingConvention=global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Winapi)]
        public extern static int IsDebuggerPresent();

        [global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("api-ms-win-core-debug-l1-1-0.dll", EntryPoint="OutputDebugStringW", CallingConvention=global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Winapi)]
        public extern static void OutputDebugString(ushort* lpOutputString);
    }
}
```

Environment:

```
> Visual studio:Version 16.11.0 
> UWP Target version： Windows 10, version 2004（build 19041） 
> All NuGet packages: Last stable version
```

The release of Xamarin.UWP have taken me too much time since the last year...
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried to use previous configuration to build ?

Comment: Usually , I only release Android build. The last success build of UWP is almost half year before, and the code changed much.  Recently, I should release to windows store. I don't change the  configuration since last success release build, but still failed now. Please give more help. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, but we have no sample code could repro your problem, could mind share [mcve], I will test on that.

Comment: Sorry! I can't repro this problem, I even don't know where is problem. If the release build directory may contain the message to identify the problem, I can send you a copy. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tired to remove third part nuget to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: I have removed all NuGet packages except Xamarin.Essentials and Xamarin.Forms, but the release build still failed.

Comment: it's hard to reproduce your problem, please try to make a blank app and add above packge for testing.

Comment: I have make a blank app and add above packages for testing. Unfortunately, the same error still existed. Thanks!

Comment: Could you mind share this blank app for us?

Comment: The blank app I mentioned before also have references to other projects. I have made a Repro after add <NetNativeReproPath>D:\myRepro</NetNativeReproPath>  to csproj. Does the Repro can be used to identify the error?

Comment: I'm afraid `NetNativeReproPath` does not support for UWP app.

Comment: The ilcRepro.zip is already created in the specified path., which contain a lots of files.  If this file could be used, I will send to you. Thanks!